# Access localstorage stoped working from when Office Add-In was loaded in the new UI

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I have an AddIn for Outlook that uses the webrowsers local storage.

After testing my AddIn on the new Outlook UI, it stoped working (in some Chromium based Browsers). I can no longer access the local storage object. `window.localStorage` is `null`.

Do I need to set any configuration to reenable it?

OWA UI its working:
[image: working UI]

OWA UI not working:
[image: not working UI]

I have made a sampel repo on [GitHub](https://github.com/LokiMidgard/TestOwaIcons).

The sample app on old UI:

[image: AddIn in old UI]

The sample app on new UI:

[image: AddIn in new UI]

I tested it in

- Brave **Not-Working** `Version 1.15.72 Chromium: 86.0.4240.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
- Edge *Working* `Microsoft Edge 44.17763.831.0 Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763`
- Chrome **Not-Working** `Version 85.0.4183.121 (Official Build) (64-bit)`
- Firefox *Working* `68.4.1esr (64-Bit)`

Comment: By new Outlook UI do you mean the New Outlook for Mac ? What Outlook version you using ? Can you share your Add-in's manifest for us to repro this issue ?

Comment: I mean the OWA UI I think we are currently running Exchange 2016. I testet it in an Office365 subscription and I had no longer access to local storage. I had posted a manifest for anolther issue on [github](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs-pr/issues/2237)

Comment: We are unable to reproduce the issue on our end. Could you please provide us a sample add-in where you could reproduce the issue?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Hi, sorry for the delay, I was not at work. I have already an Sample app on [github](https://github.com/LokiMidgard/TestOwaIcons) that will now check the `window.localStorage`.

Comment: Are you using safari?

Comment: @MaviDomates I have tested it in Brave. Since it happend using a diferent Web UI I never thought about trying diferent Browsers. I also was able to test it in Chrome and Edge (the old one). Chrome does also not work (after all Brave is based on Chrome) but the old Edge does work.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. It has been put on our backlog. We, unfortunately, have no timelines to share at this point.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT Is this backlock publick (like on Github) where I can subscribe? So I know when it is resolved.

Comment: This post remains active. It will be updated once the backlog is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable all cookies in the browser. If you're blocking 3rd party cookies you will not be able to access localStorage.